# Redirect header is not redirecting to the destined page

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect the page using `header("location: profile.php")` after I click a submit button in the login form, but the page won't redirect. The username and password just gets submitted somewhere.

Here is my main page:

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/example/login.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>welcome to noteshare</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery_popup.css" />
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/npm.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery_popup.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 450px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }</style>
</head>

<!-- Body Starts Here -->
<body id="body">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"       data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="#" id="popup" onclick="div_show()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>noteshare</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididuntut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt in culpa qui
      officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <hr>
      <img src="images/girl_studying.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
<div id="abc">
<!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
<div id="popuplogin">
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<form action="" id="form" method="post" name="form">
<img id="close" src="images/cross.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
<h2>login form</h2>
<hr id="line">
<input id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text" required>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password" required>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
<p> <a href="register.php">click here to register first</a></p>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<!-- Display Popup Button -->
</body>
<!-- Body Ends Here -->
</html>
```

and here is the login.php page that contains the `header()` function call:

```
  <?php
    session_start(); // Starting Session
    $error=""; // Variable To Store Error Message
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="noteshare";
    $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    //$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    //$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    // Selecting Database
    //$db = mysqli_select_db("noteshare", $conn);
    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
    $qry="select * from signin where password='$password' AND username='$username'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    if ($rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
    header("Location:http://localhost.com/profile.php", true, 301); exit;// Redirecting To Other Page
    } else {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I think the condition if ($row==1) evaluates to false. try if ($row)

Answer (score 0):

Did your connection with mysql is ok, then try this,

```html
header('Location:filename');
Eg: header('Location:test1.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

function [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) returns an array or NULL. Therefore

```
if ($rows == 1)
```

is never true and you won't reach the redirect with header().

You can use i.e `if (is_array($rows))` or `if (isset($rows))`

You can always insert a var_dump($rows) for debugging to see what the variable $rows looks like.

Note, HTTP code 301 is a permanent redirect. It should be 302. Or simply you can omit the second and third argument of the header() function and it will be a 302.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header("Location:profile.php"); die();
```

OR redirect with JS

```
echo '<script>window.location.href = "profile.php";</script>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an absolute URL. TLD .com is not used when working on a local server.

Change:

```
header("Location:http://localhost.com/profile.php");
```

To:

```
header("Location:http://localhost/profile.php");
```

It should work!